# Elasticsearch _validate API fails queries that _search API allows

Tags: elasticsearch

I’m trying to use the _validate API and it rejects as invalid queries where the exact body submitted works when sent to the _search API. Does _validate request body need to be different in some way?

For the “explain” result I get things like “no query registered for [fields]". Removing return fields list, it complains about filter.

Here is an example:

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d/msg,file,file-info/_validate/query?explain=true' -d '{"fields":["id"],"filter":{"not":{"and":[{"numeric_range":{"msg-size":{"gte":1000}}},{"query":{"prefix":{"content-type.verbatim":"application/"}}}]}}}' | python -mjson.tool
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0, 
        "successful": 1, 
        "total": 1
    }, 
    "explanations": [
        {
            "error": "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d-0] request does not support [fields]", 
            "index": "4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d-0", 
            "valid": false
        }
    ], 
    "valid": false
}
```

Removing fields, it reports that query does not support filter

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d/msg,file,file-info/_validate/query?explain=true' -d '{"filter":{"not":{"and":[{"numeric_range":{"msg-size":{"gte":1000}}},{"query":{"prefix":{"content-type.verbatim":"application/"}}}]}}}' | python -mjson.tool
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0, 
        "successful": 1, 
        "total": 1
    }, 
    "explanations": [
        {
            "error": "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d-0] request does not support [filter]", 
            "index": "4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d-0", 
            "valid": false
        }
    ], 
    "valid": false
}
```

Some queries do work with validate API, so it's not an across-the-board failure.

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d/msg,file,file-info/_validate/query?explain=true' -d '{"query": { "match": { "file-name": "PLEASE READ: something not important" }}}' | python -mjson.tool
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "_shards": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        "failed": 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        "successful": 1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        "total": 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "explanations": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            "explanation": "filtered(file-name:PLEASE READ: something not important)->cache(_type:file _type:file-info _type:msg)",                                                                                                       
            "index": "4af9aae4-7ec1-458d-8c50-692ddb0f2c6d-0",                                                                                                                                                                                
            "valid": true                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "valid": true                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

My understanding is _validate runs the same syntax checks etc as when you actually actually execute a query, so I am not sure what is going on.

Other details:

Elasticsearch v 1.2.1
Ubuntu Linux Precise 64

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your query in a query key to use the _validate endpoint - that's why your last example is working but your first two do not.

> Note
>
> The query being sent in the body must be nested in a query key, same
>   as the search api works [1.0.0.RC1] Added in 1.0.0.RC1. The query was
>   previously the top-level object..

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't explain why queries that are valid through _search are invalid through _validate.

Comment: And I haven't found a way that starts with :query that means the same thing as the filters I am working with.

Comment: The issue is that _validate is more restrictive than _search -

Comment: So is there no way to validate queries using the same validation performed during search execution? I have not found a way as of yet.

Comment: It's frustrating. That's what _validate is supposed to do but clearly it's limited in that it does not support every possible query you can send.